# How to do a density plot using pipes?

Tags: r, density-plot

I am trying to plot a density plot using the weatherAUS data set available in R. I have tried with the following code. But, I am not able to plot the perfect density plot of the Rainfall distribution.
With the below code my plot looks like

[image]

for dataset use -> View(weatherAUS)  # this the R in-built dataset.

So, how can I plot the density plot perfectly? I want my plot to look like the following:
[image]

```
 cities <- c("Canberra", "Darwin", "Melbourne", "Sydney")
# Build the required dataset and plot it.
weatherAUS %>%
  filter(Location %in% cities) %>%
  filter(Rainfall %>% is.na() %>% not()) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Rainfall, colour=Location, fill=Location)) +
  geom_density(alpha=0.55) +
  labs(title="Distribution of Rainfall",
       subtitle="Selective Locations",
       caption="Source: Australian Bureau of Meteorology",
       x="Rainfall",
       y="Density")
```

Comment: It does not seem weatherAUS is a dataset that comes with Base R. Have you loaded rattle to have access to it? If so, include the loaded packages in your example code.

Comment: Yeah I did add the rattle to load the dataset

Comment: You will also have to be more specific about "perfectly", which is very subjective. What do you want your plot to look like? Do you have an example image? The distribution of the rainfall data gives a very long tail, as expected.

Comment: Your second `filter` looks rather odd and it's not clear from the code how you're ending up with Temperature on the x-axis if you want rainfall.

Comment: I have not changed my x -lab and title description as I was using the code from the previous plot. Sorry for the confusion created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you are after when you say "perfect", but this might convey the information better: log-transforming the x axis to avoid that long tail. However, note that you end up with thousands of infinite values coming from doing a log10 of 0 mm of precipitation.

```r
cities <- c("Canberra", "Darwin", "Melbourne", "Sydney")
library(rattle.data)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
weatherAUS %>%
  filter(Location %in% cities,
         !is.na(Temp3pm)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Rainfall, colour = Location, fill = Location)) +
  geom_density(alpha = 0.3) +
  scale_x_log10() + # distribution is very skewed, so log-transform the axis
  labs(title = "Distribution of Rainfall",
       subtitle = "Selective Locations",
       caption = "Source: Australian Bureau of Meteorology",
       x = "Daily rainfall (mm)",
       y = "Density")
#> Warning: Transformation introduced infinite values in continuous x-axis
#> Warning: Removed 8338 rows containing non-finite values (stat_density).
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-02-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Hey, I was looking for the same plot.. thank you :)

Comment: @sreerangamneethu if you are happy with the answer, you can mark it as "accepted". Glad I could help!